# Javascript - Storing Parent and Child Values

Tags: javascript, structure, parent

I need some help... using Javascript I'm trying to create a parent-child relationship for lists and I'm not sure how to achieve this.

The objective is to have a structure depicted below:

ParentObject 1

1. PO1 List item
2. PO1 List item
3. PO1 List item
4. PO1 List item

ParentObject 2

1. P02 List item
2. P02 List item
3. P02 List item
4. P02 List item

...

I'm not looking for someone to code it out for me, I'm just looking for guidance from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object with an array as a property.

So

```
var parent = {
    childlist = [1,2,3,4,5];

}
```

You can then access the child elements with `parent.childlist[index]` to get the child at the index position of the list.  You can add a new item x to the list with `parent.childlist.push(x)`

if you want to simplify creating this multiple times you can use a constructor, like this.

```
var Parent = function(){
    this.childlist = [];
}

var parent1 = new Parent();

var parent2 = new Parent();
```